Program starts despite DisallowRun entry
When starting any Adobe application the Adobe Desktop Service.exe is automatically started. I don't want this to happen so I added an entry in the registry key Computer\HKEY_USERS\{long ID of some sort}\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\DisallowRun the entry has the name "1" and value "Adobe Desktop Service.exe". I restarted teh computer.
Indeed, if I try to start the program (Adobe Desktop Service), myself, I get an error that it is not allowed.
However starting any Adobe product starts the program as usual.
Why is this happening and what can I do to prevent it?

You need to disallow or allow specific executables. All you have done is disable the service itself

@Ramhound, you mean, like adding an entry in the Computer\HKEY_USERS\{long ID of some sort}\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\DisallowRun registry? Which is what disallows specific executables? Which is what I have done? I have not disabled any service, since this is not a service, just as it won't be a duck if someone had named it "Adobe Desktop Duck". Also an actual instruction on HOW to do what you said NEEDS to be done would have been ACTUALLY useful, but I guess that is an unrealistic expectation in this case.

You only blocked Adobe Desktop Service.exe you have blocked any other executable. If you can still run individual Adobe executables you have to block those also, in the same way, you blocked Adobe Desktop Service.exe. I came to the realization your question might be that, when you launch any Adobe application, Adobe Desktop Service.exe is starting and that’s what you wanted blocked. Your question certainly could be more clear if that’s the case.  Since your not being pleasant to other users this will be my last interaction with you.

Are you sure your Adobe application can run without that service? It is easy to disable or remove it, but that might break existing software.
If the objection is that the service continues to run after shutting Acrobat, then use a script such as that below to start the service, then start Acrobat, and finally stop the service when Acrobat closes.
net start <service>
"<full path to Acrobat application>"
net stop <service>

Make a shortcut to a batch file with that script, and set it to run as Administrator, to use net command.
If you find you do not need the service at all, set it Disabled from the Services control panel, or in Regedit, at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\<sevice> by setting Start to 4. An example is shown below:

Anther option is to try changing the extension of Adobe Desktop Service.exe, which will prevent it from running. If that breaks Adobe products, then change it back to .exe.
